# Take multiple values from Radio button using loop php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mysqli

I was building a website in which I have to store the address of multiple users and one customer can have multiple addresses. So, when customer login he can select one address and move forward. I am using a loop to display the multiple addresses of the customer and radio button to select the one address from many addresses but my code only gets the last loop result and I don't know how to select multiple values from a radio button. I think i messed it up. Please help.

```
$query = "SELECT `name`,`mobileno`, `address`, `pincode`, `landmark`, `state` FROM `user_address` 
        WHERE customer_id = (SELECT `customer_id` FROM `user` WHERE email = '{$_SESSION['email']}')";
$records=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){


echo "<label class='useradr-cont'>";
echo "<input type='radio' checked='checked' name='useradr-check'>";
echo "<span class='checkmark'></span>";


echo "<div class='useradr-body'>";

echo "<span style='font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;'>".$row['name']."</span><br>
        <input type='hidden' name='cname' value=".$row['name'].">";

echo "<span>Mobile No - ".$row['mobileno']."</span><br><br>
        <input type='hidden' name='cmobno' value=".$row['mobileno'].">";

echo "<span>Address - ".$row['address']."</span><br>
<input type='hidden' name='cadr' value=".$row['address'].">";

echo "<span>Pincode - ".$row['pincode']."</span><br>
<input type='hidden' name='cpin' value=".$row['pincode'].">";

echo "<span>Landmark - ".$row['landmark']."</span><br>
<input type='hidden' name='clandmark' value=".$row['landmark'].">";

echo "<span>State - ".$row['state']."</span><br>
<input type='hidden' name='cstate' value=".$row['state'].">";

echo "</div>";
echo "</label>";
}
```

Comment: I don't know php, so I won't be much help looking at your code, but my gut instinct says your problem is regarding use of radios -- functionally, you're only intended to select one at a time. Would checkboxes work better for you? Checkboxes are intended to be single-select OR multi-select.

Comment: My suggestion might be to set a value on that radio. Perhaps set the value to the complete address. Then, when that check is selected, will actually have a value. As it stands, there is NO value to any of the radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. My problem is solved.